# put reset button in default for code in user control page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, reset

this code in user control.ascx page

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dates.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.Dates" %>

<b>Arivval Date: </b><br />  <br />
    <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Arivval" ></asp:Calendar><br />
 <b>Depart Date: </b> <br /> <br />
 <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Depart" ></asp:Calendar>
```

and this code in web form page (default.ascx )

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HotelReservation.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.HotelReservation" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dt" TagName="Date" Src="~/Dates.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<asp:Panel  runat="server" ID="ph">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/HotelImageButton.jpg"  ID="HOTEL" runat="server"  PostBackUrl="~/HotelReservation.aspx" />
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/CarImageButton.jpg"  ID="CAR" runat="server"  PostBackUrl="~/CarReservation.aspx" />

            <h1 > Hotel Search </h1>

                           <dt:Date id="d" runat="server" />  <br />
            <b>Nights:</b> <asp:TextBox id="num" runat="server" TextMode="Number" />
            <br /> <br/>
           <b> Room Type:</b> <br /> <br />
            <asp:RadioButton id="Superior" runat="server" text="Superior" GroupName="RoomType" /> <br />
            <asp:RadioButton id="Twin" runat="server" text="Twin" GroupName="RoomType" /> <br />
            <asp:RadioButton id="Triple" runat="server" text="Triple" GroupName="RoomType" /> <br />
            <asp:RadioButton id="DeLuxe" runat="server" text="DeLuxe" GroupName="RoomType" /> <br />
            <asp:RadioButton id="Studio" runat="server" text="Studio" GroupName="RoomType" /> <br />
            <br /> <br />
            <asp:Button ID="search" Text="Search" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="Reset" Text="Reset"   runat="server" style="margin-left: 51px" Width="61px" OnClick="Clear" />


    </form>
    </asp:Panel>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in default.ascx.cs page i want to put reset button for calendar in the user control how to do it

```
protected void Clear(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    num.Text = "";
    Boolean f = false;
    Superior.Checked = f;
    Twin.Checked = f;
    Triple.Checked = f;
    DeLuxe.Checked = f;
    Studio.Checked = f;
}
```

I want to put in default.ascx.cs in clear event code to make the 2 calendars in the control page unselected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create public properties for selected dates in your user control and use them in the host page. Something like this.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Dates" %>
<script runat="server">
    public DateTime ArivvalDate
    {
        get { return Arivval.SelectedDate; }
        set { Arivval.SelectedDate = value; }
    }
    public DateTime DepartureDate
    {
        get { return Depart.SelectedDate; }
        set { Depart.SelectedDate = value; }
    }
</script>
<b>Arivval Date: </b><br />  <br />
    <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Arivval" ></asp:Calendar><br />
 <b>Depart Date: </b> <br /> <br />
 <asp:Calendar runat="server" ID="Depart" ></asp:Calendar>
```

Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/misc/Dates.ascx" TagPrefix="dt" TagName="Date" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Clear(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstRoomType.SelectedIndex = -1;
        d.ArivvalDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        d.DepartureDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    }
    protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test.Text = string.Format("Arrival: {0:M/d/yy}, Departure: {1:M/d/yy}, Room Type: {2}", d.ArivvalDate, d.DepartureDate, lstRoomType.SelectedValue);
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Reservation Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>Hotel Search </h1>

            <dt:Date ID="d" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <b>Nights:</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="num" runat="server" TextMode="Number" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <b>Room Type:</b>
            <br />
            <br />
            <%--use list instead of a set of individual RB --%>
            <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="lstRoomType">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Superior" Value="Superior" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Twin" Value="Twin" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Triple" Value="Triple" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Deluxe" Value="Deluxe" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Studio" Value="Studio" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="search" Text="Search" runat="server" OnClick="search_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Reset" Text="Reset" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 51px" Width="61px" OnClick="Clear" />
            <br />
            <asp:Literal ID="test" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```